# Track page download time for different pages for analytic purposes

Tags: javascript, analytics

I am trying to build an analytic system which tracks performance of pages of my websites.

The website is content-driven so the same template is used for all pages.
Right now we use this at page start:

```
var time  = Date.now()
```

...and at the end of page we use this:

```
date.now - time
```

...and send this difference to the tracking API, which stores this data.

Could you please suggest  any better way, as I did not find some good reviews for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Navigation Timing API provides data that can be used to measure the performance of a website. Unlike other JavaScript-based mechanisms that have been used for the same purpose, this API can provide end-to-end latency data that can be more useful and accurate.

```
function onLoad() { 
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var page_load_time = now - performance.timing.navigationStart;
  console.log("User-perceived page loading time: " + page_load_time);
}
```

There are many measured events given in milliseconds that can be accessed through the PerformanceTiming interface:

[image: performance fields description]

For details see http://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing-2/ or just experiment with window.performance object.

Actually I would recommend to use existing JS tools for such measurements. For example, http://www.devmetrics.io and their lib https://github.com/devmetrics/devmetrics-js, will provide you with this data as well as UI to see the results.

```
function onLoad() { 
  devmetrics.measurePageLoad();
}
```

[image: page load time graph]

Comment: Thanks @Andrew Andrew